# Understanding invokeAll method of the ForkJoinTask

Tags: java, multithreading

While I was reading [the javadoc about ForkJoinTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) I came across the following statement:

> This method may be invoked only from within `ForkJoinPool` computations
>   (as may be determined using method `inForkJoinPool()`). Attempts to
>   invoke in other contexts result in exceptions or errors, possibly
>   including `ClassCastException`.

What's not clear to me is what `ForkJoinContext` means here. I know what static context means, for example. It clearly defines in the [JLS 8.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3) as follows (Emphasize's mine):

> A statement or expression occurs *in a static context* if and only if
>   the innermost method, constructor, instance initializer, static
>   initializer, field initializer, or explicit constructor invocation
>   statement enclosing the statement or expression is a static method, a
>   static initializer, the variable initializer of a static variable, or
>   an explicit constructor invocation statement (§8.8.7).

Answer (score 4):

The context being discussed here is not static/non-static context.

It means that the method must be called from a thread which belongs to the `ForkJoinPool`.

So it must be called from a recursive task. Calling from anywhere else might cause exceptions/errors.